# Recursive Workbook_SheetChange

Tags: excel, vba, events

Is there a way I can temporarily disable the Workbook_SheetChange event before my while loop and restore it on wend?

I believe I have myself in a recursive loop. By dynamically changing the value and initiating a new active cell, I trip the Workbook_SheetChange event. Which would be fine except that I am in the SheetChange routine at the time.

Not good.

The purpose is to help me learn my lines for my role in a theater performance by making me type in my lines followed automatically by the next line(s) of the other actor(s) until my next line. Which, of course, represent my cues.

The idea here is to either automatically populate a cell in column A when the corresponding cell in column c is not valued "Condon" (My role in the play Haupmann) or compare (the parsed contents) of the cell in column A with (the parsed contents) of the corresponding cell in column B (through the sub CleanCode not shown).

I want to populate cell/Column A with the corresponding cell/column B ONLY WHEN I am active on the active row and the cell in column C in that row is NOT "Condon". But then I want to populate every subsequent row's column A cell with the value of its column B until its column C is again "Condon" (Or ultimately blank to stop -- but that's later)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub 'Only interested in column A activity

Dim ColA As String
Dim ColB As String
Dim CellA As Range
Dim CellB As Range

If ActiveCell.Address = "$A$1" Then    'Avoid error messages when resetting cursor
    Exit Sub
End If

Set CellA = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)    'Point back to row just processed (col A)
Set CellB = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)    ' (col B)

If Len(CellA.Value) > 0 Then   'Does previous cell in A column contain a value?
    ColA = CleanCode(CellA)    'Remove all but alpha and capitalize values in column A cell
    ColB = CleanCode(CellB)    'Remove all but alpha and capitalize values in column B cell

    If (ColA <> ColB) Then     'If they don't match show contents of Column B cell
        If (MsgBox(CellB, vbRetryCancel) = vbRetry) Then 
            CellA.Select       'Continue anyway on retry 
        End If
    Else
        While (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) <> "Condon" 'Unless cell in column C = Condon (test case)
'OOPS! I think next statement invokes a Workbook_SheetChange event
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) 'Populate cell in column A with B 
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select   'point to the next row
        Wend
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

So is there a way I can temporarily disable the Workbook_SheetChange event before my while loop and restore it on wend? Or is there even a better way?

(BTW I see that the while will not run when I choose reset, but not a worry right now)

Comment: Column B is hidden by the way.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False`, and then re-enable at the end.

Comment: Btw - `While...Wend` is old-fashioned/obsolete. `Do While...Loop` is preferable.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen I will do both. I wonder whether I should embed the Do While Loop in an "IF" statement  to check column C for "Condon" before disabling events; rather than deiable / enable every time What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the previous comment turn the event off: so here is another suggestion that You can change the code

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

to

```
Set ActiveCell= ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
```